# Why native compilation failed but no C# error (NotificationManager inheritance)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I have this code:

```cs
public class myNotificationManager : NotificationManager
{
    protected myNotificationManager(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {

    }
}
```

I have no error in Visual Studio.
But when I build the project I get this error:

```
error: constructor NotificationManager in class NotificationManager cannot be applied to given types;
public class myNotificationManager
  required: Context,Handler
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length App2    
  C:\Workspaces\Sandbox\App2\App2\obj\Debug\90\android\src\crc64bb1b55f618e11607\myNotificationManager.java
```

I understand the message but according to the dotnet documentation: [NotificationManager Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.notificationmanager.-ctor?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9#Android_App_NotificationManager__ctor_System_IntPtr_Android_Runtime_JniHandleOwnership_) the type of the constructor's parameters is *IntPtr* and *JniHandleOwnership* not *Context* and *Handler*.

From [the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager) I dont see any public constructor

It's like if the version of the class indicated in the error message is different from the one that I see in my IDE

*Android target framework version: v9.0 (API 28)*

*Android SDK Plateform installed: 28,29,30*

Comment: Normally, we would not do that. We always use the `NotificationManager` to to create the channel. You could check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications-walkthrough

Comment: NotificationManager.cs has virtual methods why can’t I override them ?  I inherit NotificationManager, if I use "myNotificationManager", in my example, I always use NotificationManager (+ my code)

Comment: If you really want to do that,  inherist the `Java.Lang.Object` instead `NotificationManager` class to override all the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have notifications,

```
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "Main")
                .SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogAlert)
                .SetContentTitle("Title")
                .SetContentText("Text")
                .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High);

            NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(context);
            manager.Notify(10, builder.Build());
```

but I don't know if it is about the notification constructor

Comment: I want to make my own specialization of the NotificationManager class, that's why I try to inherit from this class, I can't  do this from NotificationManagerCompat this class is sealed.